# Cropping GeoTIFF with GeoTools - remove NO_DATA border

Tags: geotiff-tiff, geotools

I have a raster with borders full of NO_DATA value.
Is it possible to crop a raster over a "minimum" bounding rectangle,

Legend: * - no data, + - data

```
*******
* ++**   ->  ++
* ++**       ++
*******
```

Comment: So this question is how do I find the bounds of the data area?

Comment: The question is about whether GeoTools has such built-in functionality

Comment: the other question is here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246374/cropping-geotiff-with-geotools-using-integer-indexes